# Dejagnu/expect multiline regex

Tags: regex, unit-testing, tcl, expect

I'm writing unit tests for my app in DejaGNU, and I can't match mulitiline output.

When I remove newline `\n` from output, my rules matches well.
Eg.

output: `0 123 0 123`

```
expect {
  -re "^0 \\d+ 0 \\d+$" {pass "$test_name"}
}
```

I want to have output like that:

```
0 123
0 123
```

I've tried everyting

```
"^0 \\d+\\n0 \\d+$"
"^0 \\d+\n0 \\d+$"
"^0 \\d+$\\n^0 \\d+$"
"^0 \\d+$\n^0 \\d+$"
```

But non of them works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expect does have an overall multi-line pattern space to match against, but it doesn't necessarily see what you're thinking it might. In particular, newlines can end up being transformed by the virtual terminal system. Try this:

```
expect {
    -re {^0 \d+[\r\n]{1,2}0 \d+$} {
        # Just for debugging (and you might need to write to a log...)
        binary scan $expect_out(0,string) c* byteList
        puts [join $byteList ","]
        # Now do the rest of your code
        pass "$test_name"
    }
}
```

<sup>Note that I put the RE in braces instead of double quotes, because that keeps the number of backslashes down.</sup>
Once you know what's *actually* being seen by Expect, you can code it more directly. I'd normally just say print it out without any fussing around, but since you're dealing with newlines it's easier to read the ASCII bytes.